# Replace character with another character in regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, expression

currently, this is the preg_replace string that I have.

```
$mtg_post['post_content'] = preg_replace("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "",$ability);
```

This is an example of the data contained within $ability.

```
At the beginning of your upkeep, put a doom counter on Armageddon Clock.£At the 
beginning of your draw step, Armageddon Clock deals damage equal to the number 
of doom counters on it to each player.£{4}: Remove a doom counter from Armageddon  
Clock. Any player may activate this ability but only during any upkeep step.
```

I want to replace the £ character with 2xreturn or new paragraph? in regex so the line will look like this but not quite sure how to implement this.

```
At the beginning of your upkeep, put a doom counter on Armageddon Clock.

At the beginning of your draw step, Armageddon Clock deals damage equal 
to the number of doom counters on it to each player.

{4}: Remove a doom counter from Armageddon Clock. Any player may activate 
     this ability but only during any upkeep step.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a regexp here, just use `str_replace()`:

```
$out = str_replace("£", "\n\n", $in);
```

Comment: This deletes the entire lines that have £ in them.

Comment: Not for me, nor would that make sense. Here's a demo: http://codepad.org/oho8zhgi

Comment: Yep I even manually put the text in as the variable and it removes the whole line. here's the link to the fullcode. http://codepad.org/DupoYKzY

Comment: Problem was since I was pulling from an XML file that was in utf8 I had to utf8_decode it first before replacing the string.